# gdb remote returned an error: E08 when calling completion block (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, ios6, objective-c-blocks

I'm using ARC and on iOS6 I someties get a strange crash:
gdb remote returned an error: E08

In the stacktrace the method before is on a line which calls a completion block. I read a lot about blocks and ARC, but I'm still not confident when using them in the folling context:

(simplified methods and left out some code)

```
- (void) method1: (void(^)(NSMutableArray *a)) completionBlock withFailedBlock:(void(^)(NSInteger errorCode,NSString *error)) failedBlock {
    __weak Controller *weakSelf = self;

    ...

    if(condition)
        completionBlock(weakSelf.a);

    //still do method2, since we might get updated data
    [weakself.service method2:^(NSMutableArray *a2) {
        weakSelf.shouldRefresh = NO;

        ...
        completionBlock(a2); //<-- sometimes crashes here
    } withFailedBlock:^(NSInteger errorCode, NSString *error) {
        failedBlock(errorCode, error);
    }];


} withFailedBlock:^(NSInteger errorCode, NSString *error) {
    failedBlock(errorCode, error);
}];
```

calling code:

```
[[Controller sharedController] method1:^(NSMutableArray *a) {
    //save result in model (singleton)
    [Model sharedModel].a = a;
    [weakSelf refreshUI];

} withFailedBlock:^(NSInteger errorCode,NSString *error) {
    ;//show alert

}];
```

When I inspect the block and values around it, they seem ok though. I also have NSZombie on.
My completionBlock should automatically be copied since it's referenced from within the block.

What am I missing here?
I have seen crashes on iOS5 and 4.3 also, but never gdb remote returned an error: E08. The info from the debugger was also not helpful in those cases. I am using [PLWeakCompatibility](https://github.com/plausiblelabs/PLWeakCompatibility) so that I can support __weak under iOS4.3

Comment: The crash is probably in the code the block executes, why don't you post that code?

Comment: edited the post to include this information

Comment: I got this error on a c++ project when copying an object... if that is any help.

Comment: Actually I was sending any incorrectly initialised/undefined pointer to a copy operator.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still having this problem?

Why do you need the weakSelf in this case. It does not look like you are capturing self in this situation. Does the code still crash when you leave it out?

btw, I think your method1 implementation got a bit messy when you tried to simplify it for you question.

```
- (void) method1: (void(^)(NSMutableArray *a)) completionBlock withFailedBlock:(void(^)(NSInteger errorCode,NSString *error)) failedBlock {
    ...
} withFailedBlock:^(NSInteger errorCode, NSString *error) {
    ...
}];
```

Does not look like a valid method implementation. Shouldn't it be something like:

```
- (void) method1: (void(^)(NSMutableArray *a)) completionBlock withFailedBlock:(void(^)(NSInteger errorCode,NSString *error)) failedBlock {
    ...
}
```